# Error 500 displayed on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using RoR 3.0 and a small problem has occurred that, my local site is displaying the list page clearly, but when running on production it says, We're sorry but something went wrong(500). What do i need to investigate in.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Start checking permissions on your production server

Answer (score 0):

check the production.log, if it's there and what it says.